# General function for sorting a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

Is there any general user defined function that can be used to sort any given linked list, given that it has a pointer field and a data field.

The function should not swap the data between the nodes. The swapping should be done by using the `pointers`.

I found one online, but it is using a user defined function. I'm not allowed to use any other functions, but the bubble sort one.

We were asked not to initialize any new variables, other than `temp structs` within the function. So, i can't use integers or variables like `swapped`.

**The one that i was using is as follows:**

```
/* Bubble sort the given linked lsit */
void bubbleSort(struct node *start)
{
    int swapped, i;
    struct node *ptr1;
    struct node *lptr = NULL;

    /* Checking for empty list */
    if (ptr1 == NULL)
        return;

    do
    {
        swapped = 0;
        ptr1 = start;

        while (ptr1->next != lptr)
        {
            if (ptr1->data > ptr1->next->data)
            { 
                swap(ptr1, ptr1->next);
                swapped = 1;
            }
            ptr1 = ptr1->next;
        }
        lptr = ptr1;
    }
    while (swapped);
}

/* function to swap data of two nodes a and b*/
void swap(struct node *a, struct node *b)
{
    int temp = a->data;
    a->data = b->data;
    b->data = temp;
}
```

**Given that my linked list structure is as follows:**

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};
```

Comment: Nope, not that I'm aware of. Without using a user-defined function, how do you imagine that a generic function would have any idea of **(a)** which member to use for the comparison and **(b)** whether any given node should come before or after any other arbitrary node? If you look at the `qsort` function (as found in stdlib.h) you can see that it requires a compare function to be defined. It will sort an array of whatever you like, but you have to tell it (a) how large each element is and (b) which function to use to compare 2 elements.

Comment: If it is to be truly generic you would have to supply a function to compare nodes, but you also have to handle different possible layouts of the nodes (the pointer to the next node could have different offset). Otherwise it should be possible to use a algorithm with `O(N log N)` complexity, even for singly linked lists.

Comment: I mean a user defined function. Not a function built in with c... but the function can solve the problem in a general way. Lets say it's sorting in ascending order, so i can changed it to sort in descending. Furthermore, i can edit some fields, to get the required output.

Comment: The problem with your concept of "*general*" function, is there are many types of *linked-lists* (e.g. *head/tail* (with or without a dummy first node), circular linked lists (all nodes hold data and *last->next = first*), single/double linked, etc...) The given `struct node` would fit in any of those (except double -- which needs an additional `struct node *prev;`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your case, you can use an edited version of the function that you have provided. **The swap function was omitted in here**.

```
//Sorting according to the data, ascending order
void bubbleSortLL(struct node *header){

struct node *temp1, *temp2, *temp3, *temp4, *temp5;

temp4=NULL;

while(temp4!=header->next)
{
    temp3=temp1=header;
    temp2=temp1->next;

    while(temp1!=temp4)
    {
        if(temp1->data > temp2->data)
        {
            if(temp1==header)
            {
                temp5=temp2->next;
                temp2->next=temp1;
                temp1->next=temp5;
                header=temp2;
                temp3=temp2;
            }
            else
            {
                temp5=temp2->next;
                temp2->next=temp1;
                temp1->next=temp5;
                temp3->next=temp2;
                temp3=temp2;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            temp3=temp1;
            temp1=temp1->next;
        }

        temp2=temp1->next;
        if(temp2==temp4)
            temp4=temp1;

        }
    }
}
```

This will work by passing your specified list as an argument. Nevertheless, i don't understand why you can't use the swap function.

Comment: A fairy, 10 puppies and 3 angels just died. :p For the sake of both others and yourself (in the future) I **strongly** suggest that you get into the habit of giving variable meaningful names. `temp1`, `temp2`, `temp3`, `temp4` and `temp5` are _really_ nasty names and make it unnecessarily hard to read the code. You'll thank yourself when you go back to look at old code. :)

Answer (score 2):

To get rid of the call of the swap function, replace the
function call with its content:

Instead of

```
 swap(ptr1, ptr1->next);
```

write

```
int temp = ptr1->data;
ptr1->data = ptr1->next->data;
ptr1->next->data = temp;
```

---

To swap the elements and not the data, you need
to to track the previous element.

Here a suggestion for the swap of the elements(without maybe needed NULL checks)

```
 previous->next = ptr1->next;
 previous->next->next=ptr1;
```

Instead of `ptr1=ptr1->next` you need:

```
     previous=previous->next;
     ptr1=previous->next;
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. This one should work, but we were asked not to define any new variables, other than temp structs within the function. So i can't use the integer "swapped" or the integer "temp".